# MQTT alternative (which is also compatible with C++)

Tags: mqtt

I'm quite new to the Internet of Things world and until now I've only heard of MQTT.

I want to research some other options apart from MQTT. Until now I've not found much more than Webshpere MQ and ZigBee. I know there must be dozens of other protocols, but I don't know how to select a few suitable ones without spending dozens of hours researching. That's why I reached out to a community that must know a few good ones.

What other protocols are there available?

Comment: Welcome. Generally, you will get a better and more helpful answer to your question if you show that you have already put some effort into investigating the problem on your own. Otherwise, there is a risk that people will read your question as you asking for answers to your homework (probably this is not that, but I use it as an example so you can see the risk).

Comment: Also some indication of what your specific usecase is and the reasons why you think MQTT is not suitable

Comment: I'm not saying MQTT is not suitable, in contrary I think MQTT is very suitable. But I want to research some other options too. Until now I've not found much more than Webshpere MQ and ZigBee. I know there must be dozens of other protocols, but I don't know how to select a few suitable ones without spending dozens of hours researching. That's why I reached out to a community that must know a few good ones.

Comment: https://iot.eclipse.org/standards/

Comment: @Xinq: I've added your comment into the post itself (you can [edit] to add more details when necessary) to show your research more clearly. I think this could be a great question if you reframed it as "how can I *determine* which protocols are suitable?" and asked for a general method of selecting a good protocol (you might like [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) to guide you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the biggest M2M protocol other than MQTT is [CoAP](http://coap.technology/impls.html).  While it doesn't natively implement C++ per se, it does implement C and C#, which are not huge leaps if you already have a good understanding of C++.

Another well known protocol is [AMQP](https://www.amqp.org/), for which the [AMQP-CPP library](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP) is available, enabling C++ implementation.

[WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) also appears to support C++.  There are tons of alternatives out there: just pick one and take the leap!

Comment: Are you referring to Node.js when you say Node? Node.js isn't really a protocol; it's closer to an interpreter (like the CPython interpreter for Python). Node could be useful for server-side code to respond to the devices in the field though, but you'd need to use a protocol like HTTP or Web Sockets (like you mentioned).

Comment: @Aurora0001, hmm, good point.  Edited that one out.

Answer (score 2):

MQTT is a network protocol, you can implement clients in nearly any programming language you want.

There is a MQTT client library for C++ [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/cpp/)

Comment: Yeah I know that MQTT is very versatile, but I want to know what worthy (or less worthy) alternatives are.

Comment: That's not what your question asks

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but do you understand my question now?